# What is the difference between Android user app with root access and a system app

Tags: root-access, permissions, superuser, system-apps

The answer I am looking for is in the aspect of permissions.

Can a system app do everything? Can a user app with root access (on rooted device) do everything?

If so, are they the same?

For example I want to turn the GPS on and I know it is possible on rooted device.

For that requirement should user app with root permissions be enough or should it be installed as a system app?

Comment: Check this out: [What are the differences between a system app and user app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17871/what-are-the-differences-between-a-system-app-and-user-app?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

*Undeleted my answer, though it's incomplete. I'm aware that even with root access, there are certain things a rooted app can't do. [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir.system), for example has a [System add-on](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir.system) which allows the GPS toggle to turn on GPS directly through its widget. Without this, the GPS toggle opens the screen for you to turn on the GPS manually. Maybe someone else can explain.*

An app is either a user app or a system app. A user app is stored in the `/data` folder, while a system app is stored in the `/system` folder. To access either folder, you need root access.

Giving a user app root access means it can perform actions that requires root access, such as accessing / modifying system files.

But what makes a system app unique is that it doesn't get deleted if you do a `Factory Reset`. It becomes part of the Android Operating System.

**Related questions:**

- [What are the differences between a system app and user app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17871/what-are-the-differences-between-a-system-app-and-user-app)
- [Permission is only granted to system app, in Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597125/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app-in-manifest) - see the answer here